# Iframe resize, not working

Tags: javascript, iframe, onresize

I am hosting the site locally on my xampp but, this code should have auto adjust with the site size and view it but here I am not able to resize it nor I am able to view it( I just get a blank white screen in the iframe space) what am I doing wrong, Please suggest me if there is an easier way to it .Here is the code:

```js
< SCRIPT LANGUAGE = javascript >

  function reSize() {
    try {
      var oBody = ifrm.document.body;
      var oFrame = document.all("ifrm");

      oFrame.style.height = oBody.scrollHeight + (oBody.offsetHeight - oBody.clientHeight);
      oFrame.style.width = oBody.scrollWidth + (oBody.offsetWidth - oBody.clientWidth);
    }
    //An error is raised if the IFrame domain != its container's domain
    catch (e) {
      window.status = 'Error: ' + e.number + '; ' + e.description;
    }
  }

< /SCRIPT>
                 
               
<BODY onload=reSize()>
 <iframe onresize=reSize() id=ifrm src="http:/ / www.twitter.com "></iframe>
</BODY>
```

Comment: You cannot access cross domain iframe contents if you are unable to post message from iframe, meaning getting access to iframe source code

Comment: The HTML you provided doesn't follow normal syntax and won't work correctly. That is your number one issue to start with.

Comment: does this mean I can run a website on localhost but cannot load a iframe which is not in the htdocs? @A.Wolff

Comment: normal in what way? i took that code from https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/278469 which is supposed to do a adaptive resize on the client website, in which it is not doing so.@Shaun Loftin

Comment: @VinayBanakar on link you posted: `Because you only have scripting access to pages that are hosted in the same domain, you can only access the properties to the pages that are hosted within the same domain (for example, Cross Frame Scripting). Therefore, the source document of the IFrame must be from the same domain as the page that contains the IFrame.`

Comment: that was valid. Thanks. @A.Wolf ! do u suggest me to host the site in an online domain and then try the iframe? and what if I don't use any scripting to adjusting the site size and just using a normal iframe? I tried that and I still got a blank white page.